Error de CORS en PATCH Springboot
estoy desarrollando un proyecto y me encuentro atorado con algo de cors, Trato de hacer las peticiones cors para hacer un uptade con el metodo patch, pero me bloquea, ya he tratado de configurar el CORS tanto global, como en la clase y en el metodo pero sigue sin funcionar. Cabe mencionar, que si me permite hacer todas las otras peticiones HTTP, solo PATCH no me deja.
Esta es la parte de la configuracion de la app en springboot
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                        req.requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URL)
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(),MANAGER.name(),EMPLOYEE.name(), SELLER.name())
                                .requestMatchers(GET, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_READ.name(),MANAGER_READ.name(),EMPLOYEE_READ.name(), SELLER_READ.name())
                                .requestMatchers(POST, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_CREATE.name(),MANAGER_CREATE.name(),EMPLOYEE_CREATE.name(), SELLER_CREATE.name())
                                .requestMatchers(PUT, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_UPDATE.name(),MANAGER_UPDATE.name(),EMPLOYEE_UPDATE.name(), SELLER_UPDATE.name())
                                .requestMatchers(DELETE, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_DELETE.name())
                                .requestMatchers(PATCH, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_PATCH.name(),MANAGER_PATCH.name(),EMPLOYEE_PATCH.name(), SELLER_PATCH.name())
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout(logout ->
                logout.logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                        .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext())
        );

        return http.build();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // Especifica tu origen de frontend
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }



el codigo del controlador es
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/management/typeEssential")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TypeEssentialController {
    
    private final TypeEssentialService service;
    

    
    @GetMapping("")
    private ResponseEntity<List<TypeEssential>> getAll(){
        return  ResponseEntity.ok(service.findAll());
    }
    
    @PatchMapping(value="/changeActive/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<TypeEssential> updateActiveStatus(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody boolean active) {
        try {
            TypeEssential typeEssential = service.findById(id);
            typeEssential.setActive(active);
            service.save(typeEssential);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(typeEssential);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
    
    
    @DeleteMapping (value = "/delete/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<Boolean> deleteItem(@PathVariable ("id") Long id){
        service.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(!(service.findById(id)!=null));
    }
}


y el error es
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/management/typeEssential/changeActive/1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

